# Visual Studio 15 (also 12) – Open Access database - "Could not find installable ISAM."

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am migrating a VB6 database app to VB 2015.

*NB: The first problem was the missing ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider.  Installing the “Redistributable Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable Engine” solved that problem on both my 32bit and 64bit computers.  I am testing this code on 3 computers – Win7, Win10 and Win 10 64bit.*

However, this has been followed by the “…installable ISAM” problem.  The connection has been made apparently, but the program blocks on the Open() command – giving the ISAM error.  Following in the simple test code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmTitles
    Dim BooksConnection As OleDbConnection
    Private Sub frmTitles_Load (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'connect to books database
    BooksConnection = New leDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;     DataSource = d:\VB-Data\BooksDB.accdb")
    'open the connection
    BooksConnection.Open()  ‘ Blocks here
    'display state
    lblState.Text = BooksConnection.State.ToString
    'close the connection
    BooksConnection. Close()
    'display state
    lblState.Text += BooksConnection.State.ToString
    'dispose of the connection object
    BooksConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

Please note that trying to connect an .mdb database produces the same error is produced:

```
BooksConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; DataSource = d:\VB-Data\Books.mdb")
```

Comment: [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) has lots of info on connection strings for almost all providers.  use `Data Source` not `DataSource`

Comment: Please note that this both on 32bit and 64bit machines, the Jet OLEDB Provider .dll's for 4.0, 3.0 etc. are registered.

Comment: Plutonix's reply solved the problem  - "Data Source" and not "DataSource"  A Million thanks!